# EF6 map entity through another entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, model-associations

I have users which are assigned to roles and roles which are assigned to specific system activities:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    // I want this:
    public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }

    // or even better this:
    public ICollection<ActivityCode> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public ActivityCode Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to use user activities directly, `User.Activities` to be bound through `User.Roles` and `Role.Activities`.

Of course, I can do it in code:

```
user.Activities = user.Roles
    .SelectMany(role => role.Activities)
    .Select(act => act.Id)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

but is it possible natively with EF6?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is used to represent and access the domain model.  The domain model is the logical structure of entities that make up your entire model.  So no EF provides no good mechanism for doing this.

It would make more sense to use something like a repository pattern over the domain objects and that repository might have a UserDTO which could have an activities property which contains the unified activities.  Alternatively the repository could expose a method which returns all activities for a given UserId.